# How to limit foreach in the first object of a json file

Tags: php, json

Hello I am trying to print a json file to a table. The json file is from this website https://jsonvat.com/. I want to print `$data->rates->periods->rates[0]->standard`. But I get

> "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in ..."

My code is this:

```
$data = json_decode($response);


echo '<table class="table"><thead><tr><th scope="col">Country</th><th scope="col">First</th><th scope="col">Last</th><th scope="col">Handle</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
foreach($data->rates as $rate){
    echo '<tr><th scope="row">'.$rate->name.'</th>';
    foreach($rate->periods as $period){
    echo '<td>'.$period->rates->standard.'</td><td>'.$period->rates->redused.'</td><td>'.$period->rates->super_reduced.'</td></tr>';
    }
}
echo '</tbody></table>';
```

When I change `$data = json_decode($response);` to `$data = json_decode($response, true);` and the code becomes

```
foreach($data as $rate){
        echo '<tr><th scope="row">'.$rate['name'].'</th>';
```

I get an error saying

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\test-plug\functions.php
>   on line 23.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is nested like so `$data->rates[0]->periods[0]->rates->standard` where the first `rates` has multiple objects.

Comment: This doesn't seem to print anything when I do an echo.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/Y3DRh

Comment: Ohh ok my mistake. How can I do this in a foreach?

Comment: You just want to print all of the standard rates from the file?

Comment: I want also the reduced and super_reduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your code as below:

```
$json = file_get_contents("https://jsonvat.com/");
$dataObject = json_decode($json, true);

echo '<table class="table"><thead><tr><th scope="col">Country</th><th scope="col">First</th><th scope="col">Last</th><th scope="col">Handle</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
foreach($dataObject['rates'] as $rate){
    echo '<tr><th scope="row">'.$rate['name'].'</th>';
    foreach($rate['periods'] as $period){
    echo '<td>'.$period['rates']['standard'].'</td><td>'.$period['rates']['reduced'].'</td><td>'.$period['rates']['super_reduced'].'</td></tr>';
    }
}
echo '</tbody></table>';
```

Here, I found that sometime reduced or super_reduced key does not exist in Rate key. so you need to make your code changes accordingly. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. This does work but it's not limited in [0] object

Comment: I didn't get your point that it's not limite din [0] object? can you explain it a bit?

Comment: Never mind. Your code helped me very much to solve my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $tarray = json_decode($sjson);
$newarray = array('sample'=>array());
foreach($tarray->name as $ix => $name) {
    $newarray['catalog'][]=array(
        'name'  => $tarray->name[$ix],
        'image' => $tarray->image[$ix],
        'price' => $tarray->price[$ix],
    );
}
$sjson = json_encode($newarray);
```

or you can use .split()

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. My problem is that isn't just the name but I want to print the whole json at once but only the first object

Comment: can you show me an example of your json and the response require

Comment: The json link is in the original post. I want to print the name of the country and only the current rates.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems with the various elements your trying to access (typos included).  Not all elements have a reduced (not 'redused') value, some do have a reduced1 (and reduced2) values or non at all, same with super_reduced.  In the code I've used a null coalesce (??) to set a default if no value is found.  You may want to tweak these to show something which you feel is best to show no value ...

```
    echo '<td>'.$period->rates->standard.'</td><td>'.
            ($period->rates->reduced??$period->rates->reduced1??'Non').
            '</td><td>'.($period->rates->super_reduced??'Non').'</td></tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the values with simple `foreach()` loop and set as you wish on your `<tr>` element

```
 $array = json_decode($json,1);
 foreach($array['rates'] as $k=>$v){
       echo $v['periods'][0]['rates']['standard'].PHP_EOL;
 }
```

**DEMO:**  https://3v4l.org/O9EjB

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood the second parameter of [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php): the doc tells:

> When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

So, when before you were supposed to access rates using `$data->rates`, you should now use `$data['rates']` (same for `$rate->periods` which becomes `$rate['periods']`).

You could should thus look like (untested)

```php
foreach($data['rates'] as $rate) {
   echo '<tr><th scope="row">'.$rate['name'].'</th>'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you decode as an object the nesting is `$data->rates[0]->periods[0]->rates->standard` where the first `rates` and `periods` are arrays.  Just loop them both:

```
foreach($data->rates as $rates) {
    foreach($rates->periods as $period) {
        echo $period->rates->standard . "<br />\n";
        echo $period->rates->reduced. "<br />\n";
        echo $period->rates->super_reduced . "<br />\n";
    }
}
```

If certain properties are not guaranteed to exist, then check with `isset`.

Answer (score 0):

try this can help you, or you can use this on function

```
<?php 
$count = 0;
$limit = 50;
foreach($data['rates'] as $rate) {

 //count times export data
 $count++;//first = 0 
 if($count == $limit)
   break;//if limit == count stop

   //export data
   echo $rate['name'];
}
?>
```